# Add links to div with Background Image, title and category

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image, href

Our featured image as div background and we can't link it

when we tried to use href as absolute must thing be wrong !!

We need to link div and it's title but keep category and comments urls with its

urls and not effected with post url on div

you can see live code here http://codepen.io/earngate/pen/dvVLEj

```css
#thumb-wrap {
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.thumb-element:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(27, 26, 25, 0) 0%, rgba(27, 26, 25, 0) 46%, rgba(27, 26, 25, 0.44) 65%, rgba(27, 26, 25, 1) 99%, rgba(27, 26, 25, 1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(27, 26, 25, 0) 0%, rgba(27, 26, 25, 0) 46%, rgba(27, 26, 25, 0.44) 65%, rgba(27, 26, 25, 1) 99%, rgba(27, 26, 25, 1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(27, 26, 25, 0) 0%, rgba(27, 26, 25, 0) 46%, rgba(27, 26, 25, 0.44) 65%, rgba(27, 26, 25, 1) 99%, rgba(27, 26, 25, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(27, 26, 25, 0) 0%, rgba(27, 26, 25, 0) 46%, rgba(27, 26, 25, 0.44) 65%, rgba(27, 26, 25, 1) 99%, rgba(27, 26, 25, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(27, 26, 25, 0) 0%, rgba(27, 26, 25, 0) 46%, rgba(27, 26, 25, 0.44) 65%, rgba(27, 26, 25, 1) 99%, rgba(27, 26, 25, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#001b1a19', endColorstr='#1b1a19', GradientType=0);
}

.thumb-element:hover .thumb-title,
.thumb-element:hover .thumb-summary {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background: no-repeat 50% 70%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.thumb-category {
  position: absolute;
  background: green;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 1px 15px;
  top: -30px;
  right: 15px;
}

#thumb-wrap a {
  opacity: 1.0;
  color: #fff;
}

.relative {
  position: relative
}

#thumb-first-container {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  height: 390px !important;
}

#thumb-container {
  float: right;
  width: 20%;
  height: 195px !important;
}

#thumb-container:nth-child(5n+2),
#thumb-container:nth-child(5n+5) {
  width: 30%;
}

.thumb-title {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  direction: rtl
}

.thumb-link {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.thumb-dummy {
  padding-top: 60%;
}

.thumb-element {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding-top: 19px;
  background: no-repeat 50% 50%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.thumb-content {
  width: 100%;
}

.thumb-next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}

.thumb-prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 10pt;
}
```

```html
<div id="thumb-wrap">
  <div class="thumb-content">
    <div id="thumb-first-container" class="relative">
      <div class="thumb-dummy">
      </div>
      <div title="6 Animals that Went Viral Around the World" class="thumb-element" style="background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/9GnXdDFl.jpg')">
        <div class="thumb-title">
          <div class="thumb-category">
            <a href="http://animal-site.com/?cat=102363">News</a>
          </div>
          <a class="thumb-link" title="6 Animals that Went Viral Around the World" href="http://animal-site.com/?p=106588" rel="bookmark">
            <h2>6 Animals that Went Viral Around the World </h2>
          </a>
          <div class="post-meta-info">
            <span class="post-meta"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
 <a rel="bookmark">2 weeks ago</a></span> <span class="post-meta">
 <i class="fa fa-comments"></i>
 <a href="http://animal-site.com/?p=106588#respond">0</a></span>
          </div>
          <p></p>
          <div class="thumb-summary">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not change the Div with the background into span then wrap it with an anchor. Have the main wrapper relative so the post meta(categories link,comments link) will be absolute then just increase the z-index so it will be on top.

You can try this one. I've changed the code cause there were tags aren't needed.

```css
#featured-image{
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  margin: 10px;
}

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#featured-image figure a{
  display: block;
}
#featured-image figure span{
  display: block;
  height: 390px;
  background: no-repeat 50% 50%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/9GnXdDFl.jpg');

}

#featured-image figure span:before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(27,26,25,0) 0%, rgba(27,26,25,0) 46%, rgba(27,26,25,0.44) 65%, rgba(27,26,25,1) 99%, rgba(27,26,25,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(27,26,25,0) 0%, rgba(27,26,25,0) 46%, rgba(27,26,25,0.44) 65%, rgba(27,26,25,1) 99%, rgba(27,26,25,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(27,26,25,0) 0%, rgba(27,26,25,0) 46%, rgba(27,26,25,0.44) 65%, rgba(27,26,25,1) 99%, rgba(27,26,25,1) 100%);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(27,26,25,0) 0%,rgba(27,26,25,0) 46%,rgba(27,26,25,0.44) 65%,rgba(27,26,25,1) 99%,rgba(27,26,25,1) 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(27,26,25,0) 0%,rgba(27,26,25,0) 46%,rgba(27,26,25,0.44) 65%,rgba(27,26,25,1) 99%,rgba(27,26,25,1) 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#001b1a19', endColorstr='#1b1a19',GradientType=0 );
}

#featured-image .info-wrap{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 20%; 
  z-index: 1000; 
  
}
.info-wrap {
  text-align: right;
  padding: 10px;
}
.info-wrap h2{
  font-size: 12pt;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.info-wrap a{
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.info-wrap .post-cat{
  background: green;
 border-radius: 30px;
 padding: 1px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.post-meta p a{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 3px;
}
.post-meta p a:hover,
.info-wrap h2 a:hover{
  color: green;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="featured-image">
  <figure>
    <a href="#imagelinkhere"><span title="6 Animals that Went Viral Around the World"></span></a>
  </figure>
  <div class="info-wrap">
  <h2 class="entry-title">
    <a href="#titlelinkhere">6 Animals that Went Viral Around the World</a>
  </h2>
  <div class="post-meta">
    <div class="post-cat"><a href="#cat-link">News</a></div>
    <p><a href="#comments-link">Comments</a><a href="#respond-link">Respond</a></p>
  </div><!--// end .post-meta -->
  </div><!--// end .info-wrap -->

</div><!--// end #featured-image -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add new "a" before "thumb-title" and make it absolute.
here is updated varsion [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vquu2L7x/1/)

added HTML:

```
<a href="http://google.com" class='imageLink'>Click Image</a>
```

and in CSS

```
.imageLink{
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0; 
}
```

Comment: We was tried it but not need any other text on image to click link